# "Natural Frequency" of A Quantum Simple Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, oscillators

This is perhaps a naive question, but I have just recently been introduced to QM so here it goes: we are studying the simple Q.M. Harmonic oscillator. I understand that in the classical picture, the natural frequency has a physical picture, but I struggle to find one in the Q.M. picture since the particle is not strictly bound between two points: it has a non-zero probability of being found everywhere. And also since I failed to come to a mathematical result which shows that the natural frequency in the Q.M. picture means something physical.

So is there a way to interpret natural frequency physically in the Q.M. picture?

Comment: Have you studied coherent state of the QHO yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is there a way to interpret natural frequency physically in the
>   Q.M. picture?

Consider the ground state wavefunction of the (1D) QHO - a Gaussian centered at the 'bottom' of the potential. This is a stationary state, i.e., the expectations are constant in time.

Now, *translate* the Gaussian such that the center, the point of maximum probability amplitude, is displaced from the bottom of the well. This is *not* a stationary state (it is a [coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state)) and so the wavefunction evolves non-trivially with time.

What's remarkable is that the initially translated Gaussian 'sloshes' back and forth sinusoidally with angular frequency $\omega$. (There is a nice Java applet [here](http://www.falstad.com/qm1d/) that allows you to set this up and try different parameters.) Here's the Wikipedia animation of such a state from the article:

[image]

As another answer points out, the QHO is unusual in that the *expectation* of the position (momentum too) satisfy the classical equations of motion of the harmonic oscillator. From the Wikipedia article [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem):

> Thus, for the case of a quantum harmonic oscillator, the expected
>   position and expected momentum do exactly follow the classical
>   trajectories.

In the case of the coherent state, the position expectation is, in addition, the most probable outcome of a position measurement, i.e., the particle is most likely to be found on the classical particle trajectory.

Comment: I tried making sense of this. I haven't studied coherent states yet so that part threw me off a little.

Answer (score 1):

The QM harmonic oscillator analysis is more about the effects and shape of a local potential energy function than about "where a particle is." The state function for a particle will give us a probability distribution ($|\Psi|^2$) of "finding the particle," and that's important in condensed matter physics. Just because the it has a non-zero probability of being found everywhere, doesn't mean we look everywhere. We know the best places to look.

More importantly, the QMHO analysis tells us the energy level structure, which then alows us to experimentally examine energies. If we get an equally-spaced energy structure, then we are reasonably confident that the potential energy function is QMHO-like. The energy spacing is $$\Delta E = \hbar \omega$$ which allows us to calculate the curvature of the potential.  You could think of $\omega$ as a measure of "stiffness" of the potential (although it involves the effective particle mass, too). A higher $\omega$ will be narrower than a smaller $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\dag\dagger$ 
$\newcommand\bra[1]{\langle #1 |}$
$\newcommand\ket[1]{| #1 \rangle}$
$\newcommand\braket[2]{\langle #1 | #2 \rangle}$
For a classical potential
$$V(x)=\frac{k}{2}x^2$$
where $k$ is a positive constant, the classic natural frequency is naturally obtained by solving Newton's equation of motion as given by $\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$ as a second order differential equation to get
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}.$$

For the quantum harmonic oscillator, it is instead convenient to define the potential by $$V(\boldsymbol{X})=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\boldsymbol{X}^2$$ instead of by use of $k$; where $\boldsymbol{X}^2$ is the position operator. The Hamiltonian is then clearly just $$H=\frac{1}{2m}\left( \boldsymbol{P}^2 + m^2\omega^2\boldsymbol{X}^2 \right).$$
Solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation therefore yields the energy levels $$E_n = \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)\hbar\omega$$ for a given stationary state $| n\rangle$.

Since we are interested to determine the frequency of the quantum Harmonic oscillator, we use the Hamiltonian as the generator for time evolutions, i.e.: $$H=e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$$ which gives us the time-dependent state $$| n, t\rangle = e^{-i\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)\omega t} | n, 0\rangle.$$
Indeed, **no quantum harmonic oscillator of a single state oscillates at the classical frequency** $\omega$. However, let's now consider the expectation value of position.

We can write the time-dependent wavefunction as $$| \psi, t\rangle = \sum_j a_je^{-iE_jt/\hbar}| j, 0\rangle$$ where $a_j$ are the complex amplitudes. The expectation of value of the position $x$ is then $$\langle x \rangle_\psi = \sum_{jk}a_k^* a_je^{i\left(E_k-E_j\right)t/\hbar}\bra{k}\boldsymbol{X}\ket{j} \\
    = \sum_{jk}a_k^\star a_je^{i\left(k-j\right)\omega t}\bra{k}\boldsymbol{X}\ket{j} \\
    = \ell\sum_{jk}a_k^\star a_je^{i\left(k-j\right)\omega t}\bra{k}\left(A+A^\dag\right)\ket{j} \:\because \boldsymbol{X} = \ell \left(A+A^\dag\right), \ell = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}} \\
    = \ell\sum_{jk}a_k^\star a_je^{i\left(k-j\right)\omega t} \left(\sqrt{j}\braket{k}{j-1} + \sqrt{j+1}\braket{k}{j+1}\right).$$
    Since the first term vanishes unless $k=j-1 \wedge j>0 \:\because \sqrt{j}$, and the second term vanishes unless $k=j+1$. Replacing $j$ by $j'\equiv j+1$ allows us to combine the two sums. $$ \left\langle x\right\rangle_\psi = \ell\sum_{j=1}\sqrt{j}\left(a_{j-1}^\star a_j e^{-i\omega t} + a_{j}^\star a_{j-1} e^{i\omega t}\right) \\
    = \sum_jX_j\cos(\omega t + \phi_j) $$ where $2\sqrt{j}\ell a_j^\star a_{j-1}=X_je^{i\phi_j} $. Therefore, $\left\langle x\right\rangle$ oscillates sinusoidally at the classical frequency $\omega$ regardless of the amplitudes $a_j$ like its classical counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to define a natural frequency but possibly the most intuitive is to start from the Schrodinger equation
\begin{align}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)+\frac{1}{2} kx^2 =E\psi(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}
and convert it to dimensionless form.  This is done by introducing the quantities 
\begin{align}
\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\, ,\quad 
\xi=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x \, ,\qquad 
\lambda =\frac{2E}{\hbar\omega}
\end{align}
where $\omega$ has units of inverse time, $\sqrt{\frac}{m\omega}{\hbar}$ has units of inverse length so $\xi$ is dimensionless, and $\frac{2E}{\hbar \omega}$ is dimensionless so that $\hbar\omega$ functions as the natural energy scale of the problem.

Making the appropriate substitutions transforms (1) to
the dimensionless form 
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{d\xi^2}\psi(\xi)+(\lambda-\xi^2)\psi(\xi)=0\, .
\end{align}

Following along one finds that $\omega t$ is dimensionless so that the time-dependence in the full time-dependent solution is
$\Psi_n(x,t)=e^{-i (n+1/2)\omega t}$. Of course if the system is described by an eigenstate like $\Psi_n(x,t)$, the probability density does not depend on time, but a linear combination of eigenstates would have a time-dependent probability density that would oscillate with a frequency which is a multiple of the natural frequency $\omega$.  For instance, 
\begin{align}
\Psi(x,t)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\psi_0(x)e^{-i \omega t/2}
+\psi_1(x) e^{-3i\omega t/2}\right)\, ,\\
\vert\Psi(x,t)\vert^2
&=\frac{1}{2}
\left(\vert\psi_0(x)\vert^2
+\vert\psi_1(x)\vert^2
+2\psi_0(x)\psi_1(x)\cos(\omega t)\right)\, .
\end{align}
if we assume, as is common practice, that $\psi_n(x)$ is real.